# CakePhp2 : How to get variables in an url like foo:bar/foo2:bar2/...?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, urlvariables

I'm using CakePhp2 and trying to get values of variables from a url.

My url looks like `controller/action/foo:bar/foo2:bar2/foo3:bar3` ?

When I use `$this->request['foo']` CakePhp says "*Undefined index*".

Any idea to find values of foo, foo2 and foo3?

Comment: try to make a var_dump($this->request) and see what print

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the documentation on named params.
it will most likely be in

```
$this->request->params['named']
```

or even easier/cleaner for 2.x:

```
$this->request->named
```

so debug($this->request->named) for details.

Comment: You're working with named parameters: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cakerequest

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->passedArgs
OR
$this->request->params['pass']
```

You want to access the passed arguments.

Comment: but he is talking about named params, not passed!